# Kotlin/Native can't import io.ktor.network.selector.ActorSelectorManager

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-native

I want to use TCP Sockets in Kotlin/Native using KTOR and I followed the according [tutorial](https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html). But somehow I can't import `ActorSelectorManager` from `io.ktor.network.selector` and get `Unresolved reference: ActorSelectorManager`

My `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.32"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
    maven { url = uri("http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev") }
    maven { url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx") }
}

kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val target = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("SocketStuff")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("SocketStuff")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("SocketStuff")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    target.apply {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val Main by getting
        val Test by getting
        commonMain {
            sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-network:1.5.3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if I forgot to add a dependency or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are the `ActorSelectorManager` on the JVM and the `WorkerSelectorManager` on the native target. You can use constructor function `SelectorManager()` to instantiate appropriate selector manager instance:

```
import io.ktor.network.selector.*

fun main() {
    val manager = SelectorManager()
}
```

Comment: First: thank you for your answer.
Unfortunaly, I get `This API is internal in ktor and should not be used. It could be removed or changed without notice.` Is there another way to do it? I can add `@OptIn(InternalAPI::class)` but I don't want to to that

Comment: This annotation means nothing and will be removed in version 2.0.0 so feel free to use that function.

Comment: I have just one last problem: I get `Compilation failed: Deserializer for declaration public kotlinx.coroutines/SingleThreadDispatcher|null[0] is not found` What does that mean?

Comment: Try to use coroutines library with a multi-thread support on native target: `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3-native-mt"`

Comment: I now get `Unfinished workers detected, 1 workers leaked!`

Comment: This issue is known https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1984. As a workaround, you can disable this warning by adding the following line of code: `Platform.isMemoryLeakCheckerActive = false`.

Comment: Where do I have to put that? I have tried settings.gradle.kts, build.gradle.kts and gradle.properties.

Comment: At the beginning of the `main` function for the native target. Here is an example https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/blob/ec8c4ff2dab48ca56931e23c4c34a427ea1e55e7/generic/samples/native-client/src/nativeMain/kotlin/app.kt#L6

Comment: If I add `Platform.isMemoryLeakCheckerActive = false` and `Platform.isCleanersLeakCheckerActive = false` it works. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue.  I realized the dependencies were missing

https://ktor.io/docs/server-dependencies.html#add-ktor-dependencies

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap")
}
maven {
    url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/kotlin/p/kotlin/dev")
}
```

}

And finally,

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.21")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:2.3.1")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.3.1")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-network:1.8.21")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-network-tls:1.8.21")
```

Add these to your build.gradle so you have all the necessary dependencies!